# c++: инициализация небольших массивов и заполнение их нулями

Tags: c++, c, массивы, оптимизация, память

вижу на практике, что такая конструкция

```
for (...)
{
    int arr[10] = {0};
    ...
}
```

работает быстрее, чем такая:

```
for (...)
{
    int arr[10];
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);
    ...
}
```

а с чем это связано?
интересно как это на уровне инструкций выглядит

и там и там сам массив скорее всего сидит в стеке, во втором случае вызывается функция для заполнения его нулями, а вот что происходит в первом случае?

правильно ли я понимаю, что при использовании оба случая идентичны относительно результата (т.е. все 10 ячеек всегда изначально заполнены 0)?

Comment: А где здесь C++? Где std::array? Вижу только сишный массив.

Comment: [Статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/272269/) на хабре на эту тему.

Comment: Заявления в духе "эта конструкция работает быстрее, чем эта" следует подкреплять, добавив [mcve].

Comment: @Никита Самоуков, а разве это не C++, вот если бы вы написали `а где здесь STL? Где std::array?` я бы понял, но метки `stl` у меня и не стоит ;-)

Comment: Нормальный вопрос и для с++. Просто некоторые люди очень хотят, что бы сделать с++ не похожим на си и пойти дальше, использовать все-все фичи новейших стандартов.

Comment: В первом случаи объявление есть определение, а во втором объявление и  дальнейшая инициализация.  Естественно, что лучше первый вариант(и думать не нужно второй вариант будет медленнее или нет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> интересно как это на уровне инструкций выглядит

это всегда легко узнать - https://gcc.godbolt.org/ покажет все.

Внутри интересно. я заметил, что студия на уровне /O0 /O1 не выбрасывает memset. Какой бы не был он  быстрый внутри, это вызов функции. А вот первый способ превращается где то в такое

```
xor     eax, eax
mov     ecx, 400                      ; 00000190H
rep stosb
```

то есть, мы процессору говорим, в регистре ecx - количество, в eax - данные, рядом там есть ещё начало массива. И вперед.

А в одно время ребята с Интела посмотрели на это сказали - а давайте это будет распознаваться процессором как некая макрокоманда (и копирование памяти через префикс rep) и будет исполнятся прям внутри, а то и контроллером памяти. И это реально быстро. Детали можно найти в этом документе https://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf

gcc и clang для маленьких массивов просто берет и копирует регистр eax (куда предварительно записал ноль) в память без цикла - это тоже не медленно (память то в кеше).

А вот для больших массивов даже в первом случае clang вызывает memset...

Также интересно то, что gcc умеет распознавать [memset](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) как встроенную "магическую функцию" (то есть, он знает, что она делает) и заменять ее на "правильный" код.

Поэтому делаем выводы:

- компиляторы хитры и знают много особенностей процессоров
- если компилятор не понимает, что от него хотят - сделает общий код, что бы оно работало
- минимальные изменения кода (размера массива) или версий компилятора могут приводить к большим перестроениям ассемблерных инструкций

Comment: т.е. по идее можно сделать `= {0}`, а компиляторы уже дальше сами пусть думают?

Comment: если в Вашем контексте это нормально, то да, так делать хорошо. Это и безопасно с точки зрения кода (memset часто путают параметры), и очевидно для компилятора (он понимает, что Вы делаете)

Answer (score -1):

Вот ассемблерный код :

```
square:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-52], edi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48], 0
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], 0
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], 0
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], 0
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
    nop
    pop     rbp
    ret
square2:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 64
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-52], edi
    lea     rax, [rbp-48]
    mov     edx, 40
    mov     esi, 0
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    memset
    nop
    leave
    ret
```

В первом варианте цикл сделан оптимизированно с раскруткой. А второй универсально функцией `memset`. Сама `memset` функция не может делать раскрутку цикла, так как длина массива неизвестна.

Comment: "Вот ассемблерный код" - это вы сами написали?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rvE6ax @user7860670

Comment: ну так c -O0 оба варианта не оптимизированы...

Comment: С оптимизацией ещё нужно много писать кода. Или попробовать `volatile`. @user7860670

Comment: ¿ну а какой смысл приводить ассемблер, сгенерированный без оптимизации, и еще писать *"В первом варианте цикл сделан оптимизированно с раскруткой."*?

Comment: сделал `volatile`, получил код покороче. Но оптимизатор вообще выкинул вторую функцию. Сам принцип то остался. `memset` - оптимизировать нельзя, а если вручную обнулить циклом, то оптимизатор постарается. https://godbolt.org/z/e6h5W6 @user7860670

Comment: Мне кажется, что запись в volatile переменную через указатель, с которого убран volatile, является UB. Кроме того, сам volatile по идее может препятствовать некоторым оптимизациям.

Comment: в целом, volatile и указатели это то место, где компиляторы могут делать странные вещи. И volatile точно не нужен, если мы пытаемся показать, как компилятор может оптимизировать код. В общем случае компилятор может посмотреть на код и даже выбросить memset, но если есть volatile, то он не будет иметь право это делать